# AngularJS filter and summary

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, javascript-objects, angularjs-filter

I have an object :

```
$scope.basketList = [{id : A1, name : metal},
{id : A2, name : plastic},
{id : B1, name : fiber}];

$scope.itemList = [{ id : 1, basket_id : 'A1', ctg : 'fruit', stok : 3},
{ id : 2, basket_id : 'A2', ctg : 'fruit', stock : 2},
{ id : 4, basket_id : 'A1', ctg : 'fruit', stock : 4},
{ id : 5, basket_id : 'B1', ctg : 'fruit', stock : 1},
{ id : 6, basket_id : 'B1', ctg : 'fruit', stock : 2},
{ id : 7, basket_id : 'A1', ctg : 'fruit', stock : 4},
{ id : 8, basket_id : 'A2', ctg : 'fruit', stock : 2}];
```

In HTML :

```
<div class="stock">
 <div ng-repeat="basket in $scope.basketList>
  <div>Basket : {{basket.name}}</div>
  <div ng-repeat="item in itemList | filter : {basket_id : basket.id}"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

How to filter and sum the stock.
so, the output will be like this :

- Metal

  friut, stock = 11
- Plastic

  fruit, stock = 4
- Fiber

  fruit, stock = 3

Comment: What have you tried? Anyway, I think it's a bad idea to use filters here, I'd better used directives instead.

Comment: I am just making a simple web with angular. and I have learned a couple of weeks angular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a simple answer you could create functions to calculate total stock value and "ctg". For example

```
$scope.getTotal = function(basket) {
   var totalStock = $scope.itemList.reduce(function(total, curr){
     if (curr.basket_id === basket.id) return total + curr.stock;
     return total;
   }, 0);
   return totalStock;
}

$scope.getCtg = function(basket) {
  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.itemList.length; i++) {
    if (basket.id === $scope.itemList[i].basket_id) return $scope.itemList[i].ctg;
  }
  return 'not found';
}
```

You would need to adjust your template:

```
<div class="stock">
 <div ng-repeat="basket in basketList">
   <div>Basket : {{basket.name}}</div>
   <span ng-bind="getCtg(basket)"></span>,
   <span ng-bind="getTotal(basket)"></span>  
</div>
```

Here's a complete jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2c3pmhpa/4/

Of course in real application you would probably make a more generic solution but this should work for your simple case.

Comment: thnk you for your solution sir..
This is just an illustration that has the same logic with my problem :)